# Crontab runs bash in a different way

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, debian

I'm building a backup script to run on Ubuntu.

***backup-all.sh*** file:

```
echo "bootstrap"
/home2/backup/bootstrap/backup.sh
BOOTSTRAP_STATUS=$([ "$?" == 0 ] && echo "OK" || echo "** FAIL **")

echo "sv2"
/home2/backup/sv2/backup.sh
SV2_STATUS=$([ "$?" == 0 ] && echo "OK" || echo "** FAIL **")

if [ "$BOOTSTRAP_STATUS" == "OK" ] &&  [ "$SV2_STATUS" == "OK" ] ; then
TITULO="Backup OK"
else
TITULO="Backup !FAILED!"
fi

(
        echo "Backup status"
        echo "-------------"
        echo "BOOTSTRAP_STATUS = $BOOTSTRAP_STATUS"
        echo "SV2_STATUS = $SV2_STATUS"
        echo "-------------"
) | mail -s "${TITULO}" "my@mail.org"
```

The backup.sh files ends with:

```
exit 0 # for success; OR:
exit 1 # for errors + send mail with log file
```

* backup.sh files contains rsync and mysql backup.

When the script returns 1 (error), it will also send me an e-mail telling me that's something is wrong and all steps are recorded on a log file.

** I have email calls. One for overview, and one for each "server" which gets errors.

So, If I run manually,

```
./backup-all.sh
```

Everything is nice. I receive just one mail with title "Backup OK".

If I wait cron to run the job, I receive just one mail with title "Backup !FAILED!", even though I didn't receive errors details and the log files are OK.

```
crontab -e
0 0 * * * /home2/backup/backup-all.sh
```

So, what cron job does with the condition/exit values of my scripts?

Comment: If you fail to explicitly request bash (with `#!/bin/bash`), it is likely that `[ "$?" == 0 ]` is a syntax error.

Comment: Not a syntax error really, just an invalid argument being passed to `[`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to debug, log stdout and error to log file:

```
0 0 * * * /home2/backup/backup-all.sh > /tmp/debug.log 2>&1
```

A few possibilities, `cron` does not have proper env by default or by design:

1. `rsync` and `mysqldump` not in cron env
2. add `#!/usr/bin/bash` to your bash script

Comment: Option 2 solved. The only thing is that I have to change to "#!/bin/bash". Thanks